# Can't 'file.open.read' a url within a ruby if-block

Tags: ruby, if-statement, open-uri

I want to create a ruby script which will take barcodes from a text file, search a webservice for that barcode and download the result.

First I tried to test the webservice download. In a file when I hardcode the query things work fine:

```
result_download = open('http://webservice.org/api/?query=barcode:78686112327', 'User-Agent' => 'UserAgent email@gmail.com').read
```

It all works fine.

When I try to take the barcode from a textfile and run the query I run into problems.

```
IO.foreach(filename) {|barcode| barcode

website = "'http://webservice.org/api/?query=barcode:"+barcode.to_str.chomp + "', 'User-Agent' => 'UserAgent email@gmail.com'"

website = website.to_s



mb_metadata = open(website).read
}
```

The result of this is:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://webservice.org/api/?query=barcode:78686112327', 'User-Agent' => 'UserAgent email@gmail.com' (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I can't figure out if this problem occurs because the string I generate somehow isn't  a valid url and ruby is trying to open a non-existent file, or is the issue that I am doing all this in a for loop and the file/url doesn't exist there. I have tried using open(website).write instead of open(website).read but that produces the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you get explicitly states, that there is no such file:
`http://webservice.org/api/?query=barcode:78686112327', 'User-Agent' => 'UserAgent email@gmail.com'`.

You try to pass all the parameters to `open` method using 1 big string (`website`), which is wrong. You should do it like that.

```
IO.foreach(filename) do |barcode|
  website = "http://webservice.org/api/?query=barcode:#{barcode.to_str.chomp}"
  mb_metadata = open(website, 'User-Agent' => 'UserAgent email@gmail.com').read
end
```

Comment: that's awesome. Thank you so much for your help.
I am not very experienced and focused on getting each element correct. I didn't even think to do it in the elegant fashion you have. 
Thanks again.